# get a lot of spam rejection from yandex smtp

Tags: smtp, spam-prevention, yandex

I have a program which sends email to customers using Yandex SMTP server. But I frequently get:

```
554 5.7.1 [2] Message rejected under suspicion of SPAM; https://ya.cc/1IrBc 1593708139-nzbnbCCRfk-gIZ4AKCg
```

I have set following headers on each email request:

```
headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
headers["Date"] = time.Now().Format("Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 MST")
```

How can I prevent this error? Is there any settings or header which I can set for that?

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies in your question: "program which sends email to customers". Yandex doesn't allow these type of emails. Its stated [here](https://yandex.com/support/mail/web/spam.html#troubleshooting__sending-limits)

> Messages that are similar, use a template, or contain commercial or advertizing proposals are sent from your mailbox. Yandex.Mail doesn't allow you to send these types of email. Our service is intended for actual communication between people.

I faced the similar problem. I checked the MX, SPF configuration for any misconfig but those were set correctly. The solution was, I removed the signature template/ signatures from emails and it worked fine then.

Nevertheless, you should move to Mailgun, Sendgrid or STMP2Go for your emails to avoid such issues or suspension by Yandex.